# Search btn with paging in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created gridview with paging and search a data within gridview.I have number of data and number of page if u filter  data in gridview it successfully display result with paging. After display i will click on next page because gridview will display only 10 records per page but i have more than 10 records which i have filtered so it will display page wise. Then when i click next page gridview will loads whole data from database and display but i want display only filtered record while searching data. 
**the aspx code is below**

```
<asp:Button ID="Search" Text="Search" runat="server" CssClass="searchbtn" OnClick="Search_Click" />
            <asp:GridView ID="gvEdit" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="slno" OnRowCreated="gvEdit_RowCreated" OnPageIndexChanging="gvEdit_PageIndexChanging" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" OnRowCommand="gvEdit_RowCommand">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#2D96CE" ForeColor="White" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#D4EFFD" />
                <PagerSettings  Position="Top" />
                <PagerStyle Height="8px" HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
                <PagerTemplate>
                    <table align="center" style="width: 100%;"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="width: 60%;">
                                <table align="center" width="50%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="First Page" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" runat="server" ID="ImgeBtnFirst" ImageUrl="../Images/First.jpg" />
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="Previous Page" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" runat="server" ID="ImgbtnPrevious" ImageUrl="../Images/Previous.jpg" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="    width: 8%;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblpageindx" CssClass="labelBold" Text="Page : " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ToolTip="Goto Page" ID="ddlPageSelector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSelector_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="combo_common_nowidth hide">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="Next Page" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" runat="server" ID="ImgbtnNext" ImageUrl="../Images/Next.jpg" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="Last Page" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" runat="server" ID="ImgbtnLast" ImageUrl="../Images/Last.jpg" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </PagerTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="form_key" HeaderText="FilingID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="business_key" HeaderText="BusinessKey" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ref_no" HeaderText="Reference" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="fum" HeaderText="Period" HeaderStyle-Width="11%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="filing_type" HeaderText="Filing Type" HeaderStyle-Width="19%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="business_name" HeaderText="Business" HeaderStyle-Width="13%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="filing_status" HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="View">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnViewDetails_Click" Text='<%#Eval("form_details")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="" HeaderText="Schedule1" ItemStyle-Width="6.9%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href="Schedule12290.aspx?key=<%#Eval("form_key") %>" target="_blank">
                                <img src="<%#Eval("schedule1") %>" alt="" />
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Copy">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDuplicate" runat="server"
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/grid/file_duplicate 35x35.png" OnClick="lnkbtnDuplicate_Click" ToolTip="Edit" CssClass='<%#Eval("duplicate") %>' OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to copy from previous years filing?');" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Edit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkBtnContinue" runat="server"
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/grid/edit3.png" OnClick="imgBtnContinue_Click" ToolTip="Edit" CssClass='<%# Eval("continue")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Delete">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDel" runat="server"
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/grid/delBlue.png" OnClick="imgBtnDelete_Click" ToolTip="Delete" CssClass='<%#Eval("delete") %>' OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Do you want to delete this file permanently?');" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

**and aspx.cs code is below**

```
  protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtsearch.Text != "")
            {
                if (ViewState["data"] != null)
                {
                    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["data"];
                    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                    dv.RowFilter = "ref_no Like '%" + txtsearch.Text + "%' OR fum Like '%" + txtsearch.Text + "%' OR filing_type Like '%" + txtsearch.Text + "%'OR business_name Like '%" + txtsearch.Text + "%'OR filing_status Like '%" + txtsearch.Text + "%'";
                    ViewState["filter"] = dv;
                    gvEdit.DataSource = dv;
                    gvEdit.DataBind();
                    //gvformlist.DataSource = dv;
                    //gvformlist.DataBind();

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string a = ex.Message;
        }

    }
    protected void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtsearch.Text = "";
        gvEdit.DataSource = ViewState["data"];
        gvEdit.DataBind();
        //gvformlist.DataSource = ViewState["data"];
        //gvformlist.DataBind();

    }
    protected void gvformlist_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        //gvEdit.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        //gvformlist.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        LoadFormList();

    }
    protected void gvformlist_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow pagerRow = gvEdit.TopPagerRow;
        Label pageLabel = (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("CurrentPageLabel");
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
        {
            pageLabel.Text = "Page " + (gvEdit.PageIndex + 1) + " of " + gvEdit.PageCount;
        }
    }
    protected void gvEdit_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvEdit.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        LoadFormList();

    }
    public void SetPagerButtonStates(GridView gridView, GridViewRow gvPagerRow, Page page, string DDlPager)
    {
        // to Get No of pages and Page Navigation
        int pageIndex = gridView.PageIndex;
        int pageCount = gridView.PageCount;
        ImageButton btnFirst = (ImageButton)gvPagerRow.FindControl("ImgeBtnFirst");
        ImageButton btnPrevious = (ImageButton)gvPagerRow.FindControl("ImgbtnPrevious");
        ImageButton btnNext = (ImageButton)gvPagerRow.FindControl("ImgbtnNext");
        ImageButton btnLast = (ImageButton)gvPagerRow.FindControl("ImgbtnLast");
        btnFirst.Enabled = btnPrevious.Enabled = (pageIndex != 0);
        btnNext.Enabled = btnLast.Enabled = (pageIndex < (pageCount - 1));
        DropDownList ddlPageSelector = (DropDownList)gvPagerRow.FindControl(DDlPager);
        ddlPageSelector.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 1; i <= gridView.PageCount; i++)
        {
            ddlPageSelector.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        ddlPageSelector.SelectedIndex = pageIndex;
        string strPgeIndx = Convert.ToString(gridView.PageIndex + 1) + " of "
                            + gridView.PageCount.ToString();

        Label lblpageindx = (Label)gvPagerRow.FindControl("lblpageindx");
        lblpageindx.Text += strPgeIndx;
    }
    protected void ddlPageSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvEdit.PageIndex = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex;
        LoadFormList();
    }

    protected void gvEdit_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
        {
            SetPagerButtonStates(gvEdit, e.Row, this, "ddlPageSelector");
        }
    }
    protected void gvEdit_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

I have changed code in **gvEdit_PageIndexChanging** as per someone suggestion code is below

```
protected void gvEdit_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ViewState["filter"] != null)
            {
                gvEdit.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                gvEdit.DataSource = ViewState["filter"];
                gvEdit.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                gvEdit.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                LoadFormList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string a = ex.Message;
        }


    }
```

after that i run the code and i am getting error 
error is **System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Data.DataView' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.**

Comment: why you don't use [Jquery Datatables](https://datatables.net/)? They have rich functionalities of customization.

Comment: I need without jquery...........please help me if any solution is there

Comment: Is you filtered by textbox?

Comment: Yes.... I am searching data with the help of textbox

Comment: I posted an answer. Have a look on it. I hope its your desire answer.

Comment: Just copy and paste my below code in fresh project and alter your stored procedure according to that. Then run this project and acknowledge me if this is your desire answer and marked as an answer and vote it up. If you need any help in regarding my stored procedure I will help you here.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question I try to give an answer. If you find my answer useful then mark is as answer or vote it up.

What I have done in below code is when user click on search button without input any student name it shows per page 10 records of all students and if you search by name it shows only specific students with paging. In below code I use a stored procedure and in that I put three parameters such as following:

```
@startRowIndex int 
@pageSize int
@studentname varchar(50) = NULL
```

**Default.aspx** markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gridview Pagging</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="searchbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div>
                <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" Width="100%" EmptyDataText="No Data Found!"
                    ShowFooter="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="WithOutPaging" GridLines="Horizontal">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Studentname" HeaderText="Student Names"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Studentage" HeaderText="Age"></asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="emptyrow" />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle2" />
                    <FooterStyle CssClass="footerstyle"></FooterStyle>
                    <EditRowStyle CssClass="editrowstyle"></EditRowStyle>
                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedrowstyle"></SelectedRowStyle>
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 70px;" align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnFirst" runat="server" Text="First" CommandName="First" OnCommand="ChangePage"
                    Visible="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnPrevious" runat="server" Text="Previous" CommandName="Previous"
                    OnCommand="ChangePage" Visible="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" CommandName="Next" OnCommand="ChangePage"
                    Visible="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnLast" runat="server" Text="Last" CommandName="Last" OnCommand="ChangePage"
                    Visible="False" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblPageText1" runat="server" CssClass="label" Visible="False" BackColor="Transparent"
                    BorderColor="Transparent" ForeColor="#3495D0"> Page </asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentPage" runat="server" CssClass="label" Visible="False" BackColor="Transparent"
                    BorderColor="Transparent" ForeColor="#5c5c5c"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPageText2" runat="server" CssClass="label" Visible="False" BackColor="Transparent"
                    BorderColor="Transparent" ForeColor="#3495D0"> of </asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lbltotalPages" runat="server" CssClass="label" Visible="False" BackColor="Transparent"
                    BorderColor="Transparent" ForeColor="#5c5c5c"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**Default.aspx.cs** code:

```
#region "Declaration"
private int pageSize = 10;
SqlConnection con;
string conquery = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=GridviewPagging;User ID=sa;Password = 123";
#endregion

#region "Events"
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["startRowIndex"] = 0;
        ViewState["currentPageNumber"] = 0;
    }
}
protected void ChangePage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {

        case "First":
            ViewState["currentPageNumber"] = 1;
            ViewState["startRowIndex"] = 0;

            break;
        case "Previous":
            ViewState["currentPageNumber"] = Int32.Parse(lblCurrentPage.Text) - 1;
            ViewState["startRowIndex"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["startRowIndex"]) - pageSize;

            break;
        case "Next":
            ViewState["currentPageNumber"] = Int32.Parse(lblCurrentPage.Text) + 1;
            ViewState["startRowIndex"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["startRowIndex"]) + pageSize;

            break;
        case "Last":
            ViewState["startRowIndex"] = pageSize * (Int32.Parse(lbltotalPages.Text) - 1);
            ViewState["currentPageNumber"] = lbltotalPages.Text;
            break;
    }

    this.fillgridview();

}
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fillgridview();
}

#endregion

#region "Methods"
private DataSet ds(int RowIndex, int Pagesize, string studentname)
{
    DataSet dataset;
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(conquery);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GET_STUDENT_DATA", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startRowIndex", RowIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageSize", Pagesize);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentname", studentname);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dataset = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dataset);
        }
        return dataset;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        return dataset = null;
    }
}
private void fillgridview()
{
    DataSet newds = ds(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["startRowIndex"].ToString()), pageSize, searchbox.Text.Trim());
    if (newds.Tables.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        btnFirst.Visible = true;
        btnPrevious.Visible = true;
        btnNext.Visible = true;
        btnLast.Visible = true;
        lblCurrentPage.Visible = true;
        lbltotalPages.Visible = true;
        lblPageText1.Visible = true;
        lblPageText2.Visible = true;

        ViewState["TotalRows"] = newds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0];
        newds.Tables[1].Rows.Clear();

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["currentPageNumber"]) == 0)
        {
            ViewState["currentPageNumber"] = 1;
        }
        setPages();

        this.gv.Visible = true;
        this.gv.DataSource = newds.Tables[0];
        this.gv.DataBind();
    }
}
private void setPages()
{
    lbltotalPages.Text = "";
    lblCurrentPage.Text = "";
    try
    {
        lbltotalPages.Text = CalculateTotalPages(Convert.ToDouble(ViewState["TotalRows"])).ToString();
        lblCurrentPage.Text = (ViewState["currentPageNumber"] == null ? "0" : ViewState["currentPageNumber"].ToString());

        if (Int32.Parse(lblCurrentPage.Text) == 0 | Int32.Parse(lbltotalPages.Text) == 0)
        {
            this.btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
            this.btnFirst.Enabled = false;
            this.btnNext.Enabled = false;
            this.btnLast.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["currentPageNumber"]) == 1)
            {
                this.btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
                this.btnFirst.Enabled = false;

                if (int.Parse(lbltotalPages.Text) > 0)
                {
                    this.btnNext.Enabled = true;
                    this.btnLast.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.btnNext.Enabled = false;
                    this.btnLast.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
                btnFirst.Enabled = true;

            }

            if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["currentPageNumber"]) == int.Parse(lbltotalPages.Text))
            {
                btnNext.Enabled = false;
                btnLast.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnNext.Enabled = true;
                btnLast.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
private int CalculateTotalPages(double totalrows)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(totalrows / pageSize));
}
#endregion
```

Comment: I am glad to hear this from you.

Answer (score 0):

first set `enablepagingandcallback = false` in gridview , then add

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1; //it is the datasource with filtered query which does the work
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: error is "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Data.DataView' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable."

Comment: there may be many possible reason for this error. Need to look into the code to see. can you try GridView1.EnableRowsCache=false

Comment: i looked into your code and you are trying to store DataView to ViewState. probably that causes the problem

Comment: i have edited my question as per suggestions please go through it